# God object replacement

Tags: c++, class, singleton, instance, god-object

I now trying to get rid of god objects from my server code.

At first of my server design, I decided to do `World`, and `const` containers objects as singleton.

But my server is multithreaded, and singletons there aren't good solution.

So I managed it and I moved that classes as `Core` class instance.

For example:

```
class Core
{
...
private:
World world;
CExpTable exptable;
...
};
```

`Core` on new connection is giving references to object for `Session` class.

```
new Session(io_pool.getService(), world, exptable ...);
```

I need only one instance of that objects.
But god object is bad design pattern, so I would to ask, how I can redesign that object, to avoid it, and is singleton pattern design good?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you can read many posts on why singletons are bad, for example [this](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?SingletonsAreEvil). There are many more with lots of valid points on why this pattern in most cases isn't really useful.

As for your refactoring: the best way is to go step by step. Large revolutions usually create bugs. From my experience, dismantling a god-object isn't very hard.

You can proceed as follows:

- identify a small responsibility you'd like to extract from the god-object
- design a new interface for this responsibility:

  - start writing unit-tests for the new class implementing this new interface. Make tests passing by an instance of the god-object enclosed in the new object, and just forward the calls
- having a set of unit-tests you can cut-out pieces of code from the god-object into the new object

The next step is to replace all uses of god-object class with the new interface in the context of the new responsibility, and then do it again.

If you have some *state* that needs to be used/handled by these responsibilities (like the `World` instance in your example), then you will have to make it shared. You can convert it to a `shared_ptr` for example, so it will be possible to leave it in the god-object for the course of the refactoring, and also use it in new classes.

Comment: Soo, i want to create only one instance of World class, but i have no idea where store reference/pointer of it, before i stored all in god class called Core. Can you explain me how i can store instance of world class without god clas or singleton ? Thanks.

Comment: @user3126089 I've updated my answer with one possible solution to this.

Comment: Will be good giving pointer to it from 'god class' to like a new Session(..., world pointer, ...) ?

Comment: Yes. Or to `Session`'s methods, in case it doesn't need to remember it all the time.